# Sit .SVG graphic next to menu text

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm creating a spry menu, but can't seem to get this 10x10px image to sit next to a menu item. Photoshop ex: 
[image: Example]

Comment: Please show some of your code

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is impossible to know how you're trying to implement it. However, for these types of icons it's often easier to just use something like font-awesome. Here is a JSFIDDLE of it being very easy implemented with font-awesome. http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/448/

```
<a class="navlink">
    Design <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>

@import 'http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

.navlink {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.navlink i {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```